# Tokenize strings of 2 elements and output in the following manner using exslt in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, tokenize, exslt

Input:

```
<name>Simon Jack Alex</name>
<age>21 23 22</age>
```

Desired output:

```
<details>
    <name="Simon">21</name>
    <name="Jack">23</name>
    <name="Alex">22</name>
</details>
```

The code should work for any number of values in name element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:variable name="formattedinput"> <!-- $testxml is your input document -->
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($testxml/name, '\s')"> <!-- \s means space -->
        <name><xsl:value-of select="."/></name>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($testxml/age, '\s')">
        <age><xsl:value-of select="."/></age>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable> <!-- now you have a proper format of data (you can also use this with apply templates instead of for-each) -->
<xsl:for-each select="$formattedinput/name">
    <xsl:variable name="currpos" select="position()"/>
    <person>
        <name><xsl:value-of select="."/></name>
        <!-- get related age by position -->
        <age><xsl:value-of select="$formattedinput/age[count(preceding::age) + 1 = $currpos]"/></age>
    </person>
</xsl:for-each>
```

That will not give you exactly your output, but it is not possible to name a node like `<name="name1"/>`. I tried it normally and with the `<xsl:element>` operation.